# spark sql how to create tables in databricks

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

hey guys i am new to databricks and i have been trying to create tables using spark sql but i was unable to do so due to the error  : Error in SQL statement: ParseException:
no viable alternative at input 'Create table offices(\n\tAreaCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY'(line 2, pos 31)
As i do not know what is wrong with the code as i am able to create the exact table using the below code. Do let me know if there is any suggestion or alternatives!.

```
Create table offices(
    AreaCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the primary key out

```
Create table offices(
    AreaCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL

)
```